# Set arbitrary Picture as viewfinder Picture in an Android Application

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I’m curious if it is possible to set an arbitrary picture, as the viewfinder picture, which is shown, when you start up a selfmade Android camera app, instead of the actual focused environment (it MUST NOT be necessary to take a Picture in order to achieve this).

Something like:

```
Android.Camera.setViewfinderPic(“MySimplePicture”);
```

Which results, that every time I open the camera and point towards some Objects, simply “MySimplePicture” is shown, regardless of the actual given environment.

So let me explain my problem in detail. We are currently trying to implement an augmented reality app and therefore we aim to create some test cases. The deal is, we aim to further develop our application as time passes by. Thus we want test cases which guarantee, that certain objects are always recognised correctly in the process of developing. So if we implement some new code which may influence the already existing one, we want to be able to determine that something has messed up.

Something like:

```
MatchingMethod.findPattern(“MySimplePicture, MySimplePictureWhichIsRotatedAndScaled”);
```

Should always be matched CORRECTLY (i.e. return TRUE), if NOT then I have messed up (start Refactoring!)

Please take pity on me, if this isn’t possible at all, or if there is an easier way to test matching of objects within an augmented reality app. Also I want to add, that we are using Vuforia for the AR part.

Please let me know if there is a way, I could possibly trick my Camera to show just a Picture I want to. Also feel free to tell me if there is a probably better way to achieve this.

You may excuse my English skills, I’m trying hard.

Greetings Berni

Comment: Are you saying you want the camera to track an image "MySimplePicture" and augment on top of it everytime it sees it? Is that what a normal Image Target does anyway?

Comment: No, we already have this scenario you are talking about. So we have our target image which get's recognised when we film it with our camera and an object gets shown in the scene. But we want to "automatically unit test" our app. So we want a prerecorded movie / picture of our scene, where the target image also appears (or not, depending on the testcase), so we don't have to film it ourselves. Really just for automated testing

Comment: Oh, so you want a virtual Image Target to be detected and Augment an object over it? Don't think that's possible unless you modify the camera's code separately. It's a complex process since you're basically trying to fool the camera to believe something that's not there, is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, Jacob. We’ve been afraid, that you would say something like this^^. But also we are happy that you confirm this is no easy task to achieve, thus we can now concentrate on other aspects of our app.

Comment: Yeah, as an AR Dev myself, I know how this break our hearts lol. But hey, maybe Vuforia might come up with something in their later releases. Hope for the best.